# How to stage data

Tags: database-design, database-normalization

A team I'm working with is tasked with comparing two similar database tables--they contain the same number of rows and the same number of columns, but slightly different data--so I'm writing a Java program to facilitate that process. There will be someone going through both tables row-by-row, column-by-column, comparing the data from TableA to TableB.

Now, TableA and TableB both exist in a large, slow, and ever-changing corporate databases, so I want to be able to stage them in order to 1) make my program faster and 2) make it so that the QC results aren't invalidated when the underlying data changes.

However, I'm not exactly sure how I want to stage my data. It seems as though creating two new tables within my database for the QC process would be inefficient. Database normalization techniques seem to suggest I should made a "Attribute" table, containing each individual field: Attribute_id, value, row_id (foreign key pointing to row in both TableA and TableB), attribute_type_id (foreign key pointing to a table containing lists of attribute_names).

This would allow me to do neat things like have QC "versions"--one person might say "TableA's value is correct," but then someone could go back later and say "no, tableB's is right" and I could easily store and retrieve that history. It doesn't seem correct, though, to collapse two tables down to what amounts to a big, long list like that. Also, I'm not sure how fast my staging database is so I might not want to do a lot of joins. (I know, it's silly, but our databases are slow.)

Or, alternatively, I could simply have the two tables mirror each other, and simply go row-by-row, column by column. This would be easy and wouldn't require many database queries, but it seems less efficient and would make expanding my functionality a little more difficult.

What do you think, kind reader?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'll be getting the data to stage from PowerHub, which will connect to two or more different Oracle databases, and then staging it in another Oracle database. I'm not so sure why PowerHub is so slow, but I'm new-ish to this job.

Comment: Is this something that you can do at the database level by establishing a linked server?

Comment: Actually, I believe the PowerHub server is a linked server, if my new knowledge gained from skimming Google results serves me correctly. I'll be using it to access the raw data. You can query PowerHub to get access to data from multiple databases.

Comment: Actually, normalization would suggest that having two tables containing almost identical data with identical meaning is probably a bad idea. But I'd be surprised if you can do anything *about* that problem.  It's probably better to fix the underlying *cause* of mismatched data rather than to continually compare tables.

Comment: I'm working for one of the world's biggest companies and helping manage a very fundamental source of data, so I don't think I can fix that problem! There's a whole floor devoted to data management.